# How to change cell values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google app script for sheets and I'm new to it.
I have a column with number and a hyperlink in each cell (each link and number is different).

I want to get the link then make an API request which will return a number which will replace that original number for each cell.

At the moment here is my function:

```
function getLinkUrls() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B2:B");
  var values = range.getRichTextValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j].getLinkUrl() !== null) {
        const val = values[i][j],
          url = val.getLinkUrl(),
          path = url.split('/')[3];

        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://decapi.me/twitch/followcount/${path}`),
        f = response.getContentText();
      }
    }
  }



}
```

I want to replace each cell now with f but I'm unsure how.
Table:[image]
Column B should always have hyperlink

Comment: Any example of the hyperlink, I will try and see, it is interesting

Comment: @KinSiang https://www.twitch.tv/burtlegurtle
all it does it fetch the twitch users followers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successful replace the hyperlink with the follower count, you may try if working on your side also, since I did not use `getrichtext` but `getvalue` directly:

```
function getLinkUrls1() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (var i = 2; i <= sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    var url = sheet.getRange(i,2).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
    if (url){
      var path = url.split('/')[3];
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://decapi.me/twitch/followcount/${path}`),
        f = response.getContentText();
        sheet.getRange(i,2).setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(f).build());
    } 
  }
}
```

This is my sample data:

[image]

Comment: Not quire what i mean, where the follower number is there should the orginal hyperlink, i will edit and add an image

Comment: I think i've done it based on your code above so thanks, but do you know how i can keep the hyperlink?

Comment: Ya, I am testing it now, try do it in array if possible.

Comment: could try `setRichTextValues`

Comment: Ya, you can try `setRichTextValue(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('6776')`  Value, I don't why I am getting `null` even i refer to a single cell only...

Comment: I think I have to give up, for unknown reason, I can't even obtain a `url` from a single cell with `sheet.getRange("B3").getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()` ....

Comment: You may refer to my new image, if you can accept to replace the number and have separate column for `http`, i think it is possible for me to work it out. Else, I think the function `richtextvalue` has bug with me, I will try avoid untill it really fix by Google lol

Comment: You have to format the column to plain text, i had that issue as well when i first started this. Select column > Format > Number > Plain Text

Comment: Ya, is it considered as a bug, i retry to solve it, let me continue workout on your case.

Comment: Ok, I make it now, you can give it a try if work, first time learn such time :)